# how to stop repeat timer?

Tags: objective-c

I am a beginner when it comes to iOS App development. I want to move a label from left to right until it reaches half the screen width - i.e. the label should move by 240px (the label moves left to right like a marquee).

I have used NSTimer and I want to stop the timer when the label reaches half the view's width.

I have used the following code but it moves the label out of the view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    timer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.09 target:self selector:@selector(time:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] retain];
}

- (void)time:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    label.center = CGPointMake(label.center.x+3.5, label.center.y);

    NSLog(@"point:%@", label);

    if (label.center.x < - (label.bounds.size.width/2)) {
        label.center = CGPointMake(320+(label.bounds.size.width/2), label.center.y);
    }
}
```

How can I solve this, please?

Comment: This task is a perfect job for animations. This would be the way to go unless there is some reason why you *can't* use them. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html

Comment: you can have a look at my answer in below 2 link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661720/trouble-setting-label-text-in-ios/11661920#11661920

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686642/each-charecter-animation-for-uilable/11687672#11687672

Answer (score 4):

If you want to stop the repeating timer, you can use

```
if (/*You label is in position*/)
    [myTimer invalidate];
```

But that's not the normal way to do animation in iOS, try this instead:

```
CGRect endFrame = /*The frame of your label in end position*/
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{ myLabel.frame = endFrame;}];
```

Answer (score 1):

To stop a timer, do `[timer invalidate]`.

You can't "pause" a timer, so once you do this you'll need to call another timer.

Answer (score 1):

correct way to invalidate your timer is

```
[myTimer invalidate];
myTimer = nil;
```