# loop doesnt change label as i want it to in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

i am just playing around with objective c on xcode, this may seem like a dumb question but here is my block of code, it works but it doesnt work how i want it to.

```
        int i = 10;
    int x = 0;
    do {

        printf("Count is: %i\n", x);
        NSString *Result = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%i", x];
        counting.text = Result;
        x++;
        usleep(1000000);
    } while (x < i);
```

it only changes the label to 9 at the end of the loop, it prints to console fine, but it is supposed to count from 0 to 9 and show it on the app.
i think i need todo multi threading but the examples are in java, so i cant apply them to this language

Comment: What is `counting`? A UILabel or something? Those only get drawn when the runloop has a chance to spin, which your loop is preventing. You're updating the value ten times, you're just never giving the label a chance to draw.

Comment: "show it on the app" - what does that mean?

Comment: NEVER sleep on the main thread. This locks your app. Very bad.

Comment: You need to use some sort of timer.  There are several schemes to choose from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people already mentioned in comments, the problem is because `usleep(1000000)` is freezing your main thread, who is responsible for interations with the UI, including updating it.

If you change the sleep for this line `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];`, this code should work as you expect, without the need of using another threads:

```
int i = 10;
int x = 0;
do {

    printf("Count is: %i\n", x);
    NSString *Result = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%i", x];
    counting.text = Result;
    x++;
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1]];
} while (x < i);
```

Comment: thanks for the help this seemed to work the best for me, how would i apply this when im not in a loop? or it just doesn't matter whether it is in a loop or not?

Answer (score 2):

It's not updating because you're blocking (with `usleep`) the main thread, which does all the drawing (as well as touches, and any other UI interaction). You need to set the text and then let the main thread return. You should have this thread just set up delayed calls:

```
int i = 10;
int x = 0;
do {
    printf("Count is: %i\n", x);
    NSString *Result = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%i", x];
    [counting performSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:Result afterDelay:x];
    x++;
} while (x < i);
```

Comment: You should remove the `counting.text = Result;` line from this code.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

```
int i = 10;
int x = 0;
dispatch_time_t time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0);
do {
    NSString *Result = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%i", x];
    time = dispatch_time(time, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        counting.text = Result;
    });
    x++;
} while (x < i);
```

As mentioned in the comments, there's a bunch of other things going on here that you need to be aware of. The [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661720/trouble-setting-label-text-in-ios) has some good info.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use timers rather than sleep in main thread or any other thread. please check that question

[How do I use NSTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer)