# Issue with multiple UI updating method, where only the last one updates the UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, user-interface

As you can see below I have a card game that flips a random number of cards from a deck. I have the method inside the loop which shows the card that has been flipped. But whenever I run this code it flips the card(I have an NSLog() that shows me the card that is flipped), but it doesn't display the picture of the flipped card. When I run a manual version of this, in which the user presses a button to flip the card it works perfectly.

```
- (void)automatedGame
{
    for (int i = 52; i > [_deck randomCountGuessNumber]; i--) {
        [self drawCardUI:nil];
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

I want it to flip (and show that it flipped) then wait a second, then flip (and show that it flipped) again. Any Help as to why this isn't working? Thanks!

Here is the contents of the drawDarUI method, and the method which it calls:

```
- (void)drawCardUI:(id)sender
{
    [[_Mview imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[_deck drawCard]]];
    [self updateUI];
}

- (void)updateUI
{
    [_Mview label].text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(unsigned long)[[_deck deck] count]];

    if ([[_deck deck] count] == [_deck randomCountGuessNumber])
    {
        UISegmentedControl *countSegmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(10, 150, 300, 30)];
        for (int i = [_deck theCountLow]; i <= [_deck theCountHigh]; i++) {
            [countSegmentedControl insertSegmentWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i] atIndex:(i+(-([_deck theCountLow]))) animated:1];
        }
        [countSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(countAnswered:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [self.view addSubview:countSegmentedControl];
        _start = [NSDate date];
        [[_Mview button] setEnabled:false];
    }

    if ([[_deck deck] count] == 0)
    {
        [[_Mview button] setEnabled:false];
    }
}
```

Sorry for not having that before.

Comment: What does your `drawCardUI` method look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trouble setting label text in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661720/trouble-setting-label-text-in-ios)

Comment: Also, `randomCountGuessNumber` will be called every time the loop is run, so if it generates the number in that method you'll be getting a new one every time.

Comment: Kevin do you mean the first line of updateUI?